# How to open and close a sub application in c++

Tags: c++

I am writing a c++ console application for ubuntu that acts as a rate table controller to receive user commands and send them over tcp to a table that enact the command and returns information - such as position and velocity.

I have written a js/electron application to act as a GUI for the position and velocity information.

I would like for my user to be able to type "GUION" into the console application to open the GUI. then input "GUIOFF" to close it. Using `system("cd rtgui; npm start");` I can open the GUI and it runs perfectly fine - but this is not optimal as I cannot close it using "GUIOFF" command because that same exact terminal window is inaccessible again (to my knowledge).

My question is, is there a better way than `system()` where I can access the same terminal window to call `npm start` and then `npm stop` to kill the GUI when the user desires?

Code for command is here.

```
/*************************************************
 appCommand - checks if the input is a command for this app. 
*************************************************/
bool control::appCommand(string userInput){
    // TODO - RUN THIS COUT IN DEBUG MODE ONLY
    //printf("\nchecking command: %s\n", userInput.c_str());
    
// if "HELP" send help list and return true
    if(userInput == std::string("HELP")){
        helpSection();
        return true; 
    } // if the gui is not enabled, populate it and switch the bool to true
    else if(userInput == std::string("GUION")){
        if(guiEnabled == false){
            printf("\nEnabling GUI.\n");

            system("cd rtgui; npm start");

            // switch bool
            guiEnabled = true;
        }
        // is an app command
        return true;
    } // if the gui is showing, close it.
    else if(userInput == std::string("GUIOFF")){
        if(guiEnabled == true){
            printf("\nDisabling GUI.\n");

            // TODO - Enter PROPER code to close GUI here.
            system("cd rtgui; npm stop");

            // switch bool
            guiEnabled = false;
        }
        // is an app command
        return true;
    }
    else if(userInput == string("QUIT")){
        // We want to close connections - set connected to false.
        isConnected = false;
        // is an app command
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include the OS this is for; answers will be OS-specific.

Comment: @Sneftel I said ubuntu in the first sentence. so Linux.

Comment: You can `fork()` and `exec()` this will give you the pid (process id) of the child this can be used with `kill()` to ask a program to exit. This should provide enough information to look it up.

Comment: @asynts i looked into ```fork()``` which seems to only open up a duplicate of the current process. and ```exec()``` seems to replace the calling process with the new process. I need to continue using my first process - the actual controller as it handles the ZMQ connection. The sub process (my gui) piggy backs that ZMQ connection to handle the constant position and velocity polling while the user is able to continue sending commands.

Comment: The Unix/Linux way of creating a new subprocess is `fork`() followed by `exec()` in the child, the parent process stays alive in this process. The return value of `fork()` can be used to tell if you the current process is the child or parent. There are tons of examples for this on the internet.